# Pandas Dataframe: how can i compare values in two columns of a row are equal to the ones in the same columns of a subsequent row?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe like this

```
Fruit  Color  Weight
apple   red    50
apple   red    75
apple  green   45
orange orange  80
orange orange  90
orange  red    90
```

I would like to add a column with True or False according to the fact that Fruit and Color of row x are equal to Fruit and Color of row x+1, like this:

```
Fruit  Color  Weight Validity
apple   red    50      True
apple   red    75      False
apple  green   45      False
orange orange  80      True
orange orange  90      False
orange  red    90      False
```

I have tried the following, but there are some errors I guess, I am getting wrong results:

```
g['Validity'] = (g[['Fruit', 'Color']] == g[['Fruit', 'Color']].shift()).any(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You had the right idea about shifted comparison, but you need to shift backwards so you compare the current row with the next one. Finally use an `all` condition to enforce that ALL columns are equal in a row:

```
df['Validity'] = df[['Fruit', 'Color']].eq(df[['Fruit', 'Color']].shift(-1)).all(axis=1)

df
    Fruit   Color  Weight  Validity
0   apple     red      50      True
1   apple     red      75     False
2   apple   green      45     False
3  orange  orange      80      True
4  orange  orange      90     False
5  orange     red      90     False
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative -

```
subset_df = df[['Fruit','Color']].apply(''.join, axis=1)
df['Validity'] = np.where(subset_df == subset_df.shift(-1), True,False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Similarly with other answers:

```
df['Validity']=(df[['Fruit', 'Color']]==pd.concat([df['Fruit'].shift(-1), df['Color'].shift(-1)], axis=1)).all(axis=1)

>>> print(df)
       Fruit   Color  Weight  Validity
0   apple     red      50      True
1   apple     red      75     False
2   apple   green      45     False
3  orange  orange      80      True
4  orange  orange      90     False
5  orange     red      90     False
```